# VS2013 Compiler bug with nested lambda and types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, lambda

This code compiles fine on ideone but not on Visual Studio 2013. Is it a compiler bug?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1, v2;
    typedef decltype(v1) t1;
        std::for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&](const t1::value_type& a1)
        {
                typedef decltype(v2) t2;
                std::for_each(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&](const t2::value_type& a2)
                {

                });
        });
}
```

error C2825: 't2': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

http://ideone.com/kGtTrB

Comment: Not a bug, more likely lack of support

Comment: @aaronman What's the difference? Either it supports nested lambdas or not, supports decltype or not.

Comment: Whatever floats ur boat, if it compiles on ideone than it's valid C++, MSVC is not known for its "uptodateness"

Comment: @aaronman or rather, is known for it's not-uptodateness :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does MSVC think `t2` is `std::vector<int>&`? I'd wager that `decltype(v2)` is incorrectly evaluating the type of the capture corresponding to `v2` in the closure instead of the type of `v2` in the reaching scope.

Comment: @Casey how can I test that?

Comment: Something like `static_assert(std::is_same<std::vector<int>&,t2>::value, "EXPLODE!")` should do it.

Comment: @Casey Yep, looks like it gets the reference. Another issue is that it doesn't allow to use `decltype` with uncaptured variables.